# XMLHttpRequest: Multipart/Related POST with XML and image as payload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, picasa

I'm trying to POST an image (with Metadata) to Picasa Webalbums from within a Chrome-Extension. Note that a regular post with Content-Type image/xyz works, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8243698/420615). However, I wish to include a description/keywords and the [protocol specification](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) describes a [multipart/related format](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PostPhotoWithMetadata) with a XML and data part.

I'm getting the Data through HTML5 FileReader and user file input. I retrieve a binary 
String using

```
FileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Assume this is my callback code once the FileReader has loaded the string:

```
function upload_to_album(binaryString, filetype, albumid) {

    var method = 'POST';
    var url = 'http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/' + albumid;
    var request = gen_multipart('Title', 'Description', binaryString, filetype);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", '3.0');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",  'multipart/related; boundary="END_OF_PART"');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("MIME-version", "1.0");
    // Add OAuth Token
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", oauth.getAuthorizationHeader(url, method, ''));
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // .. handle response
        }
    };
    xhr.send(request);
}
```

The gen_multipart function just generates the multipart from the input values and the XML template and produces the exact same output [as the specification](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PostPhotoWithMetadata) (apart from ..binary image data..), but for sake of completeness, here it is:

```
function gen_multipart(title, description, image, mimetype) {
    var multipart = ['Media multipart posting', "   \n", '--END_OF_PART', "\n",
    'Content-Type: application/atom+xml',"\n","\n",
    "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>", '<title>', title, '</title>',
    '<summary>', description, '</summary>',
    '<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#photo" />',
    '</entry>', "\n", '--END_OF_PART', "\n",
    'Content-Type:', mimetype, "\n\n",
    image, "\n", '--END_OF_PART--'];
    return multipart.join("");
}
```

The problem is, that the POST payload differs from the raw image data, and thus leads to a Bad Request (Picasa won't accept the image), although it worked fine when using

```
xhr.send(file) // With content-type set to file.type
```

My question is, how do I get the *real* binary image to include it in the multipart? I assume it is mangled by just appending it to the xml string, but I can't seem to get it fixed.

Note that due to an [old bug in Picasa](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=151), base64 is not the solution.

Comment: Have you tried uploading without the metadata? http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PostPhotoWithoutMetadata

Comment: As stated twice in my post, uploading the image directly without metadata works fine. I explicitly asked for a solution for sending it _with_ metadata.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method) states that the data send using the `.send()` method is converted to unicode, and encoded as UTF-8.

The recommended way to upload binary data is through [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) API. However, since you're not just uploading a file, but wrapping the binary data within XML, this option is not useful.

The solution can be found in the source code of the [FormData for Web Workers Polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002486/938089?upload-a-file-in-a-google-chrome-extension), which I've written when I encountered a similar problem. To prevent the Unicode-conversion, all data is added to an array, and finally transmitted as an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer). The byte sequences are not touched on transmission, [per specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#terminate-send).

The code below is a specific derivative, based on the [FormData for Web Workers Polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002486/938089?upload-a-file-in-a-google-chrome-extension):

```
function gen_multipart(title, description, image, mimetype) {
    var multipart = [ "..." ].join(''); // See question for the source
    var uint8array = new Uint8Array(multipart.length);
    for (var i=0; i<multipart.length; i++) {
        uint8array[i] = multipart.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
    }
    return uint8array.buffer; // <-- This is an ArrayBuffer object!
}
```

The script becomes more efficient when you use [`.readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsArrayBuffer%28%29) instead of [`.readAsBinaryString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsBinaryString%28%29):

```
function gen_multipart(title, description, image, mimetype) {
    image = new Uint8Array(image); // Wrap in view to get data

    var before = ['Media ... ', 'Content-Type:', mimetype, "\n\n"].join('');
    var after = '\n--END_OF_PART--';
    var size = before.length + image.byteLength + after.length;
    var uint8array = new Uint8Array(size);
    var i = 0;

    // Append the string.
    for (; i<before.length; i++) {
        uint8array[i] = before.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
    }

    // Append the binary data.
    for (var j=0; j<image.byteLength; i++, j++) {
        uint8array[i] = image[j];
    }

    // Append the remaining string
    for (var j=0; j<after.length; i++, j++) {
        uint8array[i] = after.charCodeAt(j) & 0xff;
    }
    return uint8array.buffer; // <-- This is an ArrayBuffer object!
}
```

Comment: Great find! Thanks for the detailed analysis and solution :)

Comment: Please note that XMLHttpRequest.send(ArrayBuffer) is deprecated.  You should use XMLHttpRequest.send(ArrayBufferView) (take of the .buffer) or the upcoming XMLHttpRequest.sendAsBinary().  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#sendAsBinary()

Comment: @pduncan Use `return uint8array;` instead of `return uint8array.buffer;`.

Comment: @RobW Thank you so much for your in-depth answer :)

Answer (score 0):

How about original gen_multipart, change the last line to:
return new Blob(multipart);

Similar code worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).