# Javascript XHR send multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a multipart/form-data content-type request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4){
         alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------275932272513031");

xhr.send('-----------------------------275932272513031 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

test

----------------------------275932272513031--');
```

Then in php I just print the `$_POST` array

```
print_r($_POST);
```

But I get an empty array each time. I expect to see

```
Array (
    name => "test"
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: @Glavić I'm doing this with an educational purpose

Comment: Please post code that reflects your real code. Your current code doesn't even run. Where are your escaped line terminators?

Comment: @RobW I'm afraid I don't know what you're talking about. Escaped line terminators?

Comment: @RobW I believe they are being automatically converted from the string, as if I inspect the request's `post` section in firebug I see that there are new lines?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support `"first line[Enter]second line"`. Instead, you have to use `"first line\nsecond line"` if you want to get a string with a line break inside it.

Comment: @RobW wow I never expected this. It always seems like the more you think an error is complicated the more it is actually not. You should post that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) has nice examples of XMLHttpRequest use, even file upload.

Comment: @php_nub_qq — But that would stop the request from submitting at all. You said you got an empty array back. How are you getting anything back?

Comment: @Quentin no idea, probably magic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code failed because you've used "Enter" instead of an escaped line break character (`\n`).
JavaScript doesn't support `"first line[Enter]second line"`. If you need a string with a line break, use `"first line\nsecond line"`.

Once you've fixed this problem, your code should work as intended (with one caveat, see final note):

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
     alert(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------275932272513031");
xhr.send('-----------------------------275932272513031\n' +
         'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\n\n' +
         'test\n\n' +
         '----------------------------275932272513031--');
```

**NOTE**: Your code will only work for payloads that consists of UTF-8 characters, **not** binary data. If you want to learn more about submitting forms with binary data via XMLHttpRequest, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073841/938089) and its linked references.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reference, really explains a lot now!

Comment: It's maybe helpful to mention that the boundary seperator is always prefixed with two (additional) dashes and suffixed with two more at the end of the body. That is if you have `...boundary=bound750` in the header then in the body you need `--bound750\n` and `--bound750--` as the last line.

Comment: ...and that dashes are not required in the boundary at all. It might make sense to change the post to `boundary=275932272513031` and then the two hyphens to each line `--275932272513031` (to clarify the requirement)